# How to add collections together that implement a common interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, interface

I have setup my classes as below.
So both collections implement a common interface - IChild.

Is there a way for a method on the parent to return the common parts of each collection please?

I am using "+" below, and I know this doesn't work, but it indicates what I am trying to do.

```
public interface IChild
{
    DateTime Date { get; }
    Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Boy : IChild
{
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime GraduationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get { return ProcedureDate; } }
}

public class Girl : IChild
{
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime WeddingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get { return ContactDate; } }
}


public Parent
{
    protected IList<Boy> _boys = new List<Boy>();
    protected IList<Girl> _girls = new List<Girl>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<Boy> Boys
    {
        get { return _boys; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Girl> Girls
    {
        get { return _girls; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<IChild> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _boys + _girls;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Cast<T>` to cast to the interface and then `Concat` to stream one sequence after the other.

```
return _boys.Cast<IChild>().Concat(_girls.Cast<IChild>()); // .NET 3.5 and greater
```

Note: If you are using .NET 3.5 you would need to perform the cast as shown here. If you are on .NET 4, you can follow [Kristian Fenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740684/how-to-add-collections-together-that-implement-a-common-interface/7740782#7740782) and omit the cast in lieu of `.Concat<IChild>`, which works because they made `IEnumerable<T>` covariant in the .NET 4 release, which allows `IEnumerable<Boy>` to be substituted when methods call for `IEnumerable<IChild>`.

```
return _boys.Concat<IChild>(_girls); // .NET 4.0 and greater
```

For completion, if you still happen to be using .NET 2.0, neither approach applies, although it's trivial to implement yourself.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<IChild> Children // .NET 2.0 and greater
{
    get
    {
        foreach (IChild boy in _boys)
            yield return boy;
        foreach (IChild girl in _girls)
            yield return girl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<IChild> Children
{
    get
    {
        return _boys.Concat<IChild>(_girls);
    }
}
```

Comment: As @Anthony Pegram you need to cast them. Misread 'IList' for 'List'. Them sneaky 'I's.

Comment: Actually, your answer works if you are on .NET 4. If you are on 3.5, you would need to invoke `Cast<IChild>`.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know they'd changed that. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

do you want common elements only, in resulting collection?

you can consider overloading + operator

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<IChild> Children 
    { 
        get 
        { 
          List<IChild> list = new List<IChild>();
          list.AddRange(Boys);
          list.AddRange(Girls);  
          return list; 
        } 
    }
```